# R - data.table sample replication

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create several random subsamples from my sample.

So, I was thinking of something like

```
library(data.table)
replicate(2, mtcars[, .SD[sample(.N,3)], ], simplify=F  )
```

Which gives me two lists

```
[[1]]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
2: 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
3: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3

[[2]]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
2: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
3: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

I wondering if it was possible to `bind` but with a sampling **identifier**, so conditional to the number of replications

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb replication 
1: 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1  1
2: 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1  1
3: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3  1
4: 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2  2
5: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  2
6: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  2
```

Something like

```
library(dplyr) 
replicate(2, mtcars[, .SD[sample(.N,3)], ], simplify=F  ) %>% bind_rows()
```

but indicating the number of replications (of course avoiding `loops`)

Thanks

Comment: Did you meant to keep it as a `list` or single data.frame

Comment: If you use `lapply(sequence(2), function(i) ...)` you can use `i` to construct a new column.

Comment: @akrun single data frame thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `.id` option in `bind_rows`

```
replicate(2, as.data.table(mtcars)[sample(.N,3)], simplify=FALSE  ) %>% 
                                bind_rows(., .id = 'replication')
```

Comment: Is it the fastest way possible with `data.table` this way ? or is there another way ? thanks

Comment: @giacomoV with `data.table`, there is `rbindlist` with `idcol` option.  I thought you want to mix up `dplyr` with `data.table` i.e. `%>% rbindlist(., idcol = "replication")`

Comment: oh sorry, no I mixed up because I didn't know how to do it with `data.table` completely. Would you mind posting also the full `data.table` solution ? thanks

Comment: @giacomoV I guess this `rbindlist(lapply(1:2, function(i) as.data.table(mtcars)[sample(1:.N, 3)]), idcol="replication")` would be one option

Comment: @giacomoV Maybe faster to just do the `replicate` on the vector of row numbers: `data.table(mtcars)[c(replicate(2, sample(.N, 3)))][, g := rep(1:2, each=3)][]`